# Understanding permissions of confluence users

Tags: permissions, confluence

I am trying hard to understand the permissions in confluence. Since I only have one instance which I don't want to screw up now, I can't test all myself right now.
I read the official pages for global permissions and space permissions, but still something is not clear.

1. Do Global permissions overrule space permissions?
2. When I remove a user from "confluence-users" group, will he be able to see a space,  when he is in a group which has space permissions?
3. What is the best way of restricting a page meaning to allow only 1 group to see it?

I am using a self hosted confluence v. 5.2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to 1:**

- Global Permissions determine the actions which a user is allowed to perform in Confluence at a site level.
- Space Permissions override the global permissions and are more restrictive
- Page permissions override space permissions and are more restrictive
- Pages inherit their permissions from the parent page or if no permissions have been added to a parent page, from the space.

The order of "openness" for a Confluence site: global permission is most open, followed by space permission, followed by page permissions.

**Answer to 2:**

When you remove a user from the `confluence-users` group, they have no more permission that an anonymous user. If anon users do not have access, neither does that user.

**Answer to 3:**

If it's just an single page or hierarchy of pages, add a view restriction to the specific page for the specific group. Otherwise, you can do this at space level.